# Why am I only seeing logoff, but no login, events in Windows Event Logs?

Tags: windows, active-directory, powershell, windows-event-log

I want to audit when every user logged into of logged off a server via RDP. When I run `Get-EventLog` or `Get-WinEvent` and filter for Login (Event ID 4624) and Logoff (Event ID 4634) events, I only am seeing Logoff events with no corresponding Login events. Why is this and how can i get the corresponding Login Events?

Comment: The logon may have occurred before the security event log wrapped. This is where you need to have logs sent to your centralized collector/SIEM.

Comment: @GregAskew logs span at least a week and contain approx 50 logoff events each day. I would expect to have a 1:1 ratio of login to logoff so I am not sure the log wrapping theory tracks.

Comment: What settings are enabled/disabled in auditpol?

Comment: @GregAskew you got it `Logon/Logoff: Logon No Auditing`.  If you put it as an answer I'll mark it as correct.